Linearity assumption on $f_{\#}$? (Hatcher, pg. 110-111)
This is coming from pg. 110-111 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology textbook. (See below photos.) At the moment, it is unclear why we are able to simply construct $f_{\#}$ such that linearity is understood: This would require $f(\sum_{j}n_j\sigma_j)=\sum_{j}n_jf(\sigma_j)$, which is unclear at the moment how this would be well-defined? If anybody can help, this would be greatly appreciated! I ask not just on my behalf, but also on behalf of those who are having similar concerns as me.



There is nothing unclear here. Recall that to give a homomorphism $f\colon F \to M$ where $F$ is a free module over some (commutative) ring $R$ and $M$ is any $R$-module, all one needs to do is to specify elements $f(e_i) \in M$ where $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a basis of $F$ ($I$ some indexing set) and then extend linearly, i.e. put
$$
  f\big(\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i e_i\big) = \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i f(e_i)
$$
for all tuples $(\alpha_i)_{i \in I}$ with $\alpha_i \in R$ and only finitely many $\alpha_i \neq 0$, and since $F$ is free, any choice of $f(e_i)$ will do (if any of this rings unfamiliar, it's a good-and-not-too-hard exercise to prove it).
...but this is exactly what Hatcher is doing, once you recall that $C_n(X)$ is the free abelian group (read: $\mathbb{Z}$-module) with basis the $\sigma\colon \Delta^n \to X$.

As somebody who is far more familiar with algebra than topology, this is a great answer. Such a simple explanation to something which otherwise can be rather confusing (especially when not explicitly stated). Thanks again!
